# What is the origin of 落ち着く?

Tags: etymology

The verb 落ち着く means 'to calm down', but neither constituent pertains to any sort of emotion. Was there originally a subject or object (e.g. *temper* coming down)?

Comment: I use this mnemonic to remember the meaning of the word 困ったことが頭から落ちて、心理がいい所に着くのは「落ち着く」と言います。

Answer (score 4):

落ちる means "to go down" and 着く means "to arrive" or "to settle", and 落ち着く is a rather simple combination of the two verbs. Just like English "settle" has multiple meanings, 落ち着く can mean "to (psychologically) settle down", "to establish in residence", "to become stable", "to establish a conclusion", etc.